# ERROR: pull access denied, repository does not exist or may require authorization: server message: insufficient_scope: authorization failed

Tags: c#, docker, asp.net-core

I am trying to run my first .Net Core Web API(Core 2.2) on Docker in local host. I enabled Docker support(Linux) while creating the project.

**Docker File**

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.2-aspnetcore-runtime AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.2-sdk AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["SampleApp/SampleApp.csproj", "SampleApp/"]
RUN dotnet restore "SampleApp/SampleApp.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/SampleApp"
RUN dotnet build "SampleApp.csproj" -c Release -o /app

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "SampleApp.csproj" -c Release -o /app

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "SampleApp.dll"]
```

When I try to run the API on Docker from VS, I get the following error

```
Error   CTP1001 An error occurred while attempting to build Docker image.
```

and when I looked into the output window

```
1>------ Build started: Project: SampleApp, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
1>SampleApp -> E:\Sandbox\ContainerDeployment\SampleApp\SampleApp\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.2\SampleApp.dll
1>docker build -f "E:\Sandbox\ContainerDeployment\SampleApp\SampleApp\Dockerfile" -t sampleapp:dev --target base  --label "com.microsoft.created-by=visual-studio" "E:\Sandbox\ContainerDeployment\SampleApp"
1>#1 [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile
1>#1 transferring dockerfile: 32B done
1>#2 [internal] load .dockerignore
1>#2 sha256:0237a52bf01ebc117c468d73e0fc890d42166c17898aa5c4fd0fd96dcaee67e8
1>#1 sha256:bb73acd705ce58a2a5ccfdd8d06dc6e46e04a03a430562efdf99961870d2e178
1>#2 transferring context: 34B done
1>
1>#2 DONE 0.0s
1>
1>#3 sha256:2209054a124f7bc1424fa6735d588f36916bcec272f45a5e3e54f7288e65d73e
1>#3 [internal] load metadata for docker.io/microsoft/dotnet:2.2-aspnetcore-runtime
1>#1 DONE 0.0s
1>#3 ERROR: pull access denied, repository does not exist or may require authorization: server message: insufficient_scope: authorization failed
1>------
1>------
1> > [internal] load metadata for docker.io/microsoft/dotnet:2.2-aspnetcore-runtime:
1>failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to create LLB definition: pull access denied, repository does not exist or may require authorization: server message: insufficient_scope: authorization failed
1>C:\Users\gopalk\.nuget\packages\microsoft.visualstudio.azure.containers.tools.targets\1.4.10\build\Container.targets(258,5): error CTP1001: An error occurred while attempting to build Docker image.
1>Done building project "SampleApp.csproj" -- FAILED.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: Is there a specific reason for working with .NET Core 2.2? The newest LTS version is 6.0.

Comment: You can check if the version you are trying to pull actually exists on dockerhub: https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-dotnet-aspnet?tab=description

Comment: @fbede I only have Core 2.2 on my machine. How do I change the DockerFile to use the latest? Do I need to install the latest Core on my machine?

Comment: If you are using Visual Studio you can use the Visual Studio Installer to install .NET 6 and all the templates that come with it. Then you should either recreate your project with .NET version 6, or upgrade you existing projects to .NET 6 and the re-generate your dockerfile, You can generate a Dockerfile in VS by right clicking the project file --> add --> docker support, before these steps you should delete your existing dockerfile.

Comment: @fbede yeah it helped. Pls provide as answer will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.NET Core version 2.2 is not supported anymore, the current LTS .NET version is 6.0. You can see the existing image versions of ASP.NET Core runtime on [docker hub](https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-dotnet-aspnet?tab=description).

Updating .NET version on your machine:

If you are using Visual Studio you can use the Visual Studio Installer to install .NET 6 and all the templates that come with it. Then you should either recreate your project with .NET version 6, or upgrade you existing projects to .NET 6 and then re-generate your dockerfile, You can generate a Dockerfile in Visual Studio by right clicking the project file --> add --> docker support, before these steps you should delete your existing dockerfile.